# mysql - Fatal error: Call to a member function

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to Create a login screen and I get an Error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\login\classes\Mysql.php on line 19

```
    <?php 

require_once 'includes/constants.php';

class Mysql {
    private $conn;

    function __construct() {
        $this->conn = new mysqli (DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or die('There was a problem connecting to the database.');  
    }

    function verify_Username_and_Pass($un, $pwd) {

        $query = "SELECT *
                    FROM users
                    WHERE username = ? AND password = ?
                    LIMIT 1";

        if($stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query)) {
            $stmt->bind_param('ss', $un, $pwd);
            $stmt->execute();

            if($stmt->fetch()) {
                $stmt->close();
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Constants.php

```
<?php
// Define constants here

define('DB_SERVER', '192.168.2.50:3306');
define('DB_USER', 'user');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'pass');
define('DB_NAME', 'membership');
```

Comment: Do you mean `new mysqli()`?

Comment: `__construct` (double underscore)

Comment: `mysql` is NOT an object, never has been, and never will be.

Comment: ok guys fixed the code and 2 new errors

Comment: >Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in >C:\xampp\htdocs\login\classes\Mysql.php on line 9

Comment: your constants are wrong i guess or the credentials itself

Comment: credential are correct

Comment: mysql says diffrent...

Answer (score 0):

There's no object 'mysql' in php. Try [mysqli](https://www.php.net/mysqli)

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the "user" has a grant to the database membership. here it is

```
grant all on membership.* to user@localhost identified by 'pass'
```

Comment: you need to use it in Mysql. you can use phpMyAdmin